# A cond-> threading macro alternative that refers last threaded state inside predicate?

Tags: clojure

Say I have this fn

```
(let [{:keys [a b c d] :as params} {:a 1 :b 1 :c nil :d nil}] 
  (cond-> params
    a       (update :b inc)
    (= b 2) (assoc :c "here")
    c       (assoc :d "here")))
```

what I get

```
;;=> {:a 1, :b 2, :c nil, :d nil}
```

what I want:

```
;;=> {:a 1, :b 2, :c "here", :d "here"}
```

Possible syntax:

```
(let [params {:a 1 :b 1 :c nil :d nil}] 
  (cond$-> params
    (:a $)       (update :b inc)
    (= (:b $) 2) (assoc :c "here")
    (:c $)       (assoc :d "here")))
```

Is this or a similar solution already implemented somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you are with a simple implementation:

```
(defmacro cond$->
  ([value] value)
  ([value cond body & clauses]
   (assert (even? (count clauses)))
   `(cond$-> (let [~'$ ~value]
               (if ~cond (-> ~'$ ~body) ~'$))
             ~@clauses)))
```

It basically just creates a form on the first condition and body. If the condition matches then the value of the next `cond$->` call will be `body` othervise the original value is used. It uses recursion to process all clauses.

Usually it is better to let the user choose what symbol would be used for binding the value:

```
(defmacro cond-as->
  ([value sym] value)
  ([value sym cond body & clauses]
   (assert (even? (count clauses)))
   `(cond-as-> (let [~sym ~value]
                 (if ~cond ~body ~sym))
               ~sym
               ~@clauses)))


(let [params {:a 1 :b 1 :c nil :d nil}]
  (cond-as-> params $
             (:a $)       (update $ :b inc)
             (= (:b $) 2) (assoc $ :c "here")
             (:c $)       (assoc $ :d "here")))
```

Comment: Another implementation of the same idea here: https://juxt.pro/blog/posts/condas.html

Answer (score 1):

I can see how that might be useful.  You can find [my take on it here](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#literate-threading-macro):

```
(let [params {:a 1 :b 1 :c nil :d nil}]
  (cond-it-> params
    (:a it)        (update it :b inc)
    (= (:b it) 2)  (assoc it :c "here")
    (:c it)        (assoc it :d "again")))

;=> {:a 1, :b 2, :c "here", :d "again"}
```

---

Implementation:

```
(defmacro cond-it->
  [expr & forms]
  (let [num-forms (count forms)]
    (when-not (even? num-forms)
      (throw (IllegalArgumentException. (str "num-forms must be even; value=" num-forms)))))
  (let [cond-action-pairs (partition 2 forms)
        cond-action-forms (for [[cond-form action-form] cond-action-pairs]
                            `(or (when ~cond-form) ~action-form)) ]
    `(it-> ~expr ~@cond-action-forms)))
```